# How to exclude a number from 3 numbers that is not min and max, elegant solution[python]?

Tags: python

There are 3 numbers given, need to print min, then max, then the number in between.
I dont want to write it using ifs, I m seeking more elegant solution to find a number that's not min and max out of 3.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
m = max(a,b,c)
minim = min(a,b,c)
print(m)
print(minim)

l = new list(a,b,c)

#how to exclude a 3rd element from a list that's not min and max?
number = list - m - minim 
print(number)
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: `new_list = [m, minim]`

Comment: @roganjosh i have updated it sir, pls kindly look and help me

Comment: `sorted([a,b,c])[1]` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands, ooh i did not even know about this sorted() function..

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. What you've posted is not valid python. For 10k rep, I would have expected you can do equality checks. Why do you need to exclude the "middle" value here, since you never reference it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply sort the list - minimum and maximum will be at the ends, and the middle number in the middle. Use index access (`[]`) to fetch individual elements:

```
numbers = sorted((a, b, c))
print('minimum:', numbers[0])
print('maximum:', numbers[2])
print('middle :', numbers[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
m = max(a,b,c)
minim = min(a,b,c)
print(m)
print(minim)

l = [a,b,c]

#sum - max - min
number = sum(l) - m - minim 
print(number)
```